# PHP strtotime incrementing by weekdays

Tags: php, strtotime

Today is Friday, April 17, 2015.  In my app, it automatically generated a "due date" for each assignment.  It's set to "5 business days".  To accomplish this, We use:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+5 weekdays"));
```

However, today, this output "04/26/2015".  Why?  That's a sunday.  Why doesn't it give me the 24th, which is what I want?

DEMO: http://codepad.org/2wvnypOC

P.S. After speaking to my boss, we switched to `strtotime("+5 days")`, but I'm still curious what was wrong with `"weekdays"`.

Comment: PHP version?  Looked at bugs.php.net?  "Sunday" is the part that suggests old bug....https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61642

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.38.  My original thought was a timezone issue.

Comment: [Bug #61642 modify("+5 weekdays") returns Sunday](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61642)

Comment: going off topic... Is there a `\DateTime` approach now that is preferable?  I tend to shun `date` / `strtotime` these days.

Comment: @salathe [It's not a bug, it's a feature!](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BrnfdXpIMAAAyTn.jpg:large)

Comment: @salathe: Didn't think to check that, but ok... seems like this is (was) a PHP bug.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @ficuscr I just tried: `$date = new DateTime("2015-04-17"); $date->modify("+5 weekdays"); echo $date->format("Y-m-d");` with the same result...

Answer (score 6):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61642).

It has been fixed in >= 5.5.0.

So you'll need to work around it or upgrade your php version.

```
<?php
$today = strtotime('2015-04-17 00:00:00');

echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+5 weekdays", $today));
echo "\n";
echo phpversion( );
?>
```

[Working in 5.6*](http://ideone.com/ElLwet)